# I would like to select >= as.Date('2008-01-01 ') and the NAs

Tags: r, date, na, lubridate

I have tried

1. subset(df,df$date >= as.Date('2008-01-01'),na.rm = FALSE)
2. subset(df,df$date >= as.Date('2008-01-01'),na.omit = FALSE)

I'm losing all the people who have NAs too. Please suggest a way to sort it out

I tried subset(df,df$date >= as.Date('2008-01-01'),na.rm = FALSE)

Comment: Would you mind to share some sample data for we to understand your problem and give an answer to you?

Comment: You could try `df[df$date >= as.Date('2008-01-01') | is.na(df$date),]`.

Comment: @JilberUrbina - Sorry I'm working on a secure data set on a virtual machine and I'm unable to copy anything out.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the `?subset` help page, it doesn't have any arguments named `na.rm` or `na.omit`. Those aren't magic keywords. They're common arguments that some (but not all) functions take, and you need to look at the function's help page to see if they work with a certain function.

Also, the point of using `subset` rather than just `[` is that you don't have to use `data$` after passing the `data` argument.

```
subset(df, date >= "2008-01-01" | is.na(date))
```

This should work to keep rows where the date is >= 2008-01-01 OR where the date is `NA`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using `filter` from `dplyr` package: instead of `subset`:

```
library(dplyr)
# create tibble
dat <- tibble(x = c(rep(as.Date('2008-01-01'),10)))

# add NA to tibble       
set.seed(123)
df <- as.data.frame(lapply(dat, \(x) replace(x, sample(length(x), .3*length(x)), NA)))

# filter all  2008-01-01 and NA
df %>% 
  filter(x == "2008-01-01" | is.na(.))
```